# inverse FFT in shader language?

Tags: math, opengl, directx, shader

does anyone know an implementation of the inverse FFT in HLSL/GLSL/cg ... ?

It would save me much work.

Best,
heinrich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DirectX11 comes with a FFT example for compute shaders (see [DX11 August SDK Release Notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/aa937789.aspx)). As PereAllenWebb points out, this can be also used for inverse FFT.

Edit: If you just want a fast FFT, you could try the CUFFT, which runs on the GPU. It's part of the CUDA SDK. The AMCL from AMD also has a FFT, which is currently not GPU accelerated, but this will be likely added soon.

Answer (score 6):

Do you already have a FFT implementation? You may already be aware, but the inverse can be computed by reversing the order of the N inputs, taking the FFT over those, and dividing the result by N.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a 1D FFT on 7800GTX hardware back in 2005. This was before CUDA etc so I had to resort to using Cg and manually implementing the FFT.

I have two FFT implementations. One is a Radix2 Decimation in Time FFT and the other a Stockham Autosort FFT. The stockham would perform around 2-4x faster than a CPU (at the time 3GHz P4 single core) for larger sizes (> 8192) but for smaller sizes the CPU was faster as it doesn't have to shift data to/from the GPU.

If you're interested in the shader code feel free to contact me and I'll send it over by email. It was from a personal project so not covered by any commercial copyright. I would imagine that CUDA (and similar) implementations would massively outperform my implementation, however from a learning perspective you can't get better than to write or study the code yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look at OpenCL which is a standard for general purpose computing on graphics (and other) hardware.
The wikipedia article contains a OpenCL example for a standard FFT:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL#Example

If you are on a Mac with OS X 10.6, you just need to install the developer tools to get started with OpenCL development.
I also heard that hardware vendors already provide basic OpenCL driver support on Windows.

Comment: I guess opencl under windows is supported by nvidia using CUDA.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I just found that AMD also provides an SDK called  "ATI Stream" which offers OpenCL support. http://developer.amd.com/gpu/ATIStreamSDKBetaProgram/Pages/default.aspx